# parsing json (from pylons) using jquery

Tags: jquery, json, pylons

I have set up a pylons server to accept requests of the form "/searcher?q=blahblah".  This returns some nice json of the form:

```
[{"name":"onefish","type":"one"},{"name":"twofish",type:"two"}]
```

I get this using the javascript:

```
function search() {
   var query = $('#search_box').val();
   $.getJSON('/searcher',
      {
         q: query
      },
      function(data) {
         $.each(data,function(index,element) {
            $(body).append($('<div>',{text: element.name}));
         }
      }
   );
}
```

This successfully queries the server when called and it is called (the server gives response code 200).  However, the code does not add anything to the body.  The same nothing happens when I replace `$(body).append(...);` with something like `$('#some_id').html(...);`.  Is there something wrong with my query, my parsing, or my output?

Comment: erm...stackoverflow deleted the element...

Comment: what happens if you use `data[0].name` and no loop, just as a test, and did you console log the object and see that result in the console, so you're sure that's the returned result ?

Comment: there is a new error in the console: "body is not defined"

Comment: because it needs to be in quotes.  stupid question.

Comment: This question has answers and can't be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this myself.  `body` needs to be in quotes...